# if dentro de um ng-class no angularJS

Tags: angularjs

porque eu não consigo fazer essa seguinte verificação no meu ng-class?

```
setClass(sessao.tipo_2 != 3D ? sessao.tipo_3:sessao.tipo_2)"
```

de acordo com a lógico do short-if, essa syntax está certa não?

Answer (score 4):

O `short-if` está correto. Entretanto `ng-class` possui um comportamento de avaliação diferenciado. Você está chamando uma função(`setClass`) que não será re-avaliada.

já que o Angular trabalha com *dirty-checking*, você tem duas possibilidades:

- Popule uma variável no `$scope` contendo o valor final da classe que deseja utilizar; ou
- realize uma avaliação `short-if` simples, sem chamada de função.

Exemplos abaixo:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  
  $scope.sessao = {
    tipo_2: 'D3',
    tipo_3: 'D4'
    }
  
  $scope.variavelDeClasse = $scope.sessao.tipo_3;
 
}
```

```css
.D3{
  color:red;
  }

.D4{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      <div ng-class='variavelDeClasse'>Exemplo do 1º tipo</div>
      
      <div ng-class='sessao.tipo_2 != "D3" ? sessao.tipo_3 : sessao.tipo_2'>Exemplo do 2º tipo</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se você já conseguiu a resposta, mas me apareceu a mesma dúvida agora e utilizei assim:

```
<div ng-class="minha_variavel > 0 ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-12'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data-ng-class="{'classeAqui': sessao.tipo_2 != 3D, 'classeAqui':  sessao.tipo_2 == 3D }"
```

Você deve informar um JSON de configuração para o ng-class onde você vai passar 
key: Classe
value: condição.

```
Objeto = { key : condição }
```